# Add text on MediaElement fullscreen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, grid, textblock, mediaelement

I'd like to add text on WindowsPhone 8.1 MediaElement fullscreen mode, but I cannot get it visible.
Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="MyMedia" IsFullWindow="True" MarkerReached="MyMedia_MarkerReached"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MediaTitles" Text="Hello World" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,240,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="99" Width="270" FontSize="48" />
</Grid>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property IsFullWindow="True" is causing the problem. As you might know by now. If I want the media element full screen I usually add it to the grid and span across 1 for column and row. Something like below:

```
<MediaElement 
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
```

This gives the same effect as full screen on the device. And you can see your Hello world text in the Designer.

Comment: Thank you Dane. Designer is showing 'Hello World' now.

Comment: btw, wrapping TextBlock by Popup helps and it's possible to show the text even when IsFullWindow is set to true.

Comment: @Sqeezer Thank you for sharing. Appreciate it.